# How to launch cppunit test?

Tags: c++, testing, netbeans, cppunit

I am trying to run cppunit for the first time but I get following error. I have already installed but I think there is a problem with the **cppunit-config**  Anyone has an idea how to fix this?
I have seen a report bug on nebeans but I don't know how to run cppunit-config from terminal?

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230617

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/exercise1
make[2]: `dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/exercise1' is up to date.
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-tests-conf
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/exercise1
make[2]: `dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/exercise1' is up to date.
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/tests/TestFiles
g++       -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/tests/TestFiles/f1 build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/tests/tests/newtestclass.o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/tests/tests/newtestrunner.o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main_nomain.o  `cppunit-config --libs`   
/bin/sh: cppunit-config: command not found
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "CppUnit::TestResult::addListener(CppUnit::TestListener*)", referenced from:
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::TestResult::TestResult(CppUnit::SynchronizedObject::SynchronizationObject*)", referenced from:
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::TestResult::~TestResult()", referenced from:
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::TestRunner::run(CppUnit::TestResult&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::TestRunner::addTest(CppUnit::Test*)", referenced from:
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::TestRunner::TestRunner()", referenced from:
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::TestRunner::~TestRunner()", referenced from:
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::CompilerOutputter::write()", referenced from:
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::CompilerOutputter::CompilerOutputter(CppUnit::TestResultCollector*, std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::CompilerOutputter::~CompilerOutputter()", referenced from:
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      CppUnit::AutoRegisterSuite<newtestclass>::AutoRegisterSuite()in newtestclass.o
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::registerFactory(CppUnit::TestFactory*)", referenced from:
      CppUnit::AutoRegisterSuite<newtestclass>::AutoRegisterSuite()in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::unregisterFactory(CppUnit::TestFactory*)", referenced from:
      CppUnit::AutoRegisterSuite<newtestclass>::~AutoRegisterSuite()in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::isValid()", referenced from:
      CppUnit::AutoRegisterSuite<newtestclass>::~AutoRegisterSuite()in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestResultCollector::TestResultCollector(CppUnit::SynchronizedObject::SynchronizationObject*)", referenced from:
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::TestResultCollector::~TestResultCollector()", referenced from:
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::BriefTestProgressListener::BriefTestProgressListener()", referenced from:
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::BriefTestProgressListener::~BriefTestProgressListener()", referenced from:
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase::addTest(CppUnit::Test*)", referenced from:
      newtestclass::addTestsToSuite(CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase&)         in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase(CppUnit::TestSuite&, CppUnit::TestNamer const&, CppUnit::TestFixtureFactory&)", referenced from:
      newtestclass::suite()      in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase::~TestSuiteBuilderContextBase()", referenced from:
      newtestclass::suite()      in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase::~TestSuiteBuilderContextBase()", referenced from:
      CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContext<newtestclass>::~TestSuiteBuilderContext()in newtestclass.o
      CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContext<newtestclass>::~TestSuiteBuilderContext()in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestCase::run(CppUnit::TestResult*)", referenced from:
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<newtestclass>in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestCase::TestCase(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      CppUnit::TestCaller<newtestclass>::TestCaller(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, void (newtestclass::*)(), newtestclass*)in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestCase::~TestCase()", referenced from:
      CppUnit::TestCaller<newtestclass>::~TestCaller()in newtestclass.o
      CppUnit::TestCaller<newtestclass>::~TestCaller()in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestNamer::TestNamer(std::type_info const&)", referenced from:
      newtestclass::getTestNamer__()       in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestNamer::~TestNamer()", referenced from:
      ___tcf_0 in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestSuite::TestSuite(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      newtestclass::suite()      in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestSuccessListener::wasSuccessful() const", referenced from:
      _main in newtestrunner.o
  "CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase::getTestNameFor(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
      newtestclass::addTestsToSuite(CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase&)         in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase::makeTestFixture() const", referenced from:
      CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContext<newtestclass>::makeFixture() const   in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::Test::findTestPath(CppUnit::Test const*, CppUnit::TestPath&) const", referenced from:
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<newtestclass>in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::Test::findTestPath(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, CppUnit::TestPath&) const", referenced from:
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<newtestclass>in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::Test::getChildTestAt(int) const", referenced from:
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<newtestclass>in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::Test::resolveTestPath(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<newtestclass>in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::Test::checkIsValidIndex(int) const", referenced from:
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<newtestclass>in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::Test::findTest(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<newtestclass>in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestCase::getName() const", referenced from:
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<newtestclass>in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestLeaf::countTestCases() const", referenced from:
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<newtestclass>in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestLeaf::doGetChildTestAt(int) const", referenced from:
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<newtestclass>in newtestclass.o
  "CppUnit::TestLeaf::getChildTestCount() const", referenced from:
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<newtestclass>in newtestclass.o
  "typeinfo for CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase", referenced from:
      typeinfo for CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContext<newtestclass>in newtestclass.o
  "typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCase", referenced from:
      typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCaller<newtestclass>in newtestclass.o
  "vtable for CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase", referenced from:
      CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase(CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase const&)in newtestclass.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/tests/TestFiles/f1] Error 1
make: *** [.build-tests-impl] Error 2


BUILD TESTS FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 236ms)
```

Comment: I found the answer here :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJLG44eSG6U

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem, and found the solution after some digging in the web. In my case, I have cppunit installed by Homebrew on Mavericks, and Netbeans version is 8.1. Like OP mentioned, Netbeans complains that `/bin/sh: cppunit-config: command not found` even though I can run `cppunit-config` from the terminal. This eliminates PATH related concerns. Running netbeans from the terminal is a temp fix but I found [that](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=227010#c4) there is a real fix for that.

Steps:

1. In the Projects view under `Test Files` folder, right-click on the Test Folder and go to `Properties`. (If you don't have a Test Folder yet, right-click on `Test Files` and say `new CppUnit Test`)
2. Go to `linker` section and click on `Libraries`
3. You will see some lines starting with `cppunit-`, remove them all
4. `Add Option`, select `Other Option` and type in `-lcunit`
5. Click on `Ok`.

Now, right-click on the Test Folder, and then `Test` command should run the test properly.

Comment: Hi, I've been been following this to try and get my Netbeans setup working with cppunit, I followed all the steps and it didnt work, I changed -lcunit in step 4 to be -lcppunit and it works. Isn't cUnit a different library? is this a typo on your end or am I missing something? thanks

Comment: @Scriptable -lcppunit was my first option, but couldn't get it worked. It might  be something related to my local. I am glad if you could get it worked.